# Output mallopt M_CHECK_ACTION error to log file

Tags: c, io-redirection, logfile, double-free

I'm trying to protect my process from a potential rouge code that might cause a double-free scenario using mallopt(M_CHECK_ACTION, 3).

Is there a way to output the error in case of a double-free to a log file? 
My process already redirects stderr (i.e "error" calls are logged to a file), but this specific error is printed to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_ environment variable.
`# LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_="yes" ./<you-program-name>`

Comment: I don't have access to that setup anymore, but it looks like your answer is the one I was looking for. I'll recreate the setup to test. Tanks!